# How to distribute a conditional through an n-dimensional array

Tags: arrays, ruby, conditional-statements

`[a, b].fetch(x)` is notionally equivalent to the following method:

```
def fetch(x)
  if x == 0
    a
  elsif x == 1
    b
  end
end
```

This generalises, e.g. `[[a, b], [c, d]].fetch(x)` is equivalent to:

```
def fetch(x)
  if x == 0
    [a, b]
  elsif x == 1
    [c, d]
  end
end
```

which is also equivalent to:

```
def fetch(x)
  [
    if x == 0
      a
    elsif x == 1
      c
    end,
    if x == 0
      b
    elsif x == 1
      d
    end
  ]
end
```

In this case, the conditional has been distributed into each of the elements within the array.

If I have some n-dimensional array, how can I dynamically define `#fetch(x)` for that array:

```
def define_fetch(some_array)
  define_method :fetch do |x|
    # ???
  end
end

define_fetch([[[a, b], [c, d]], [[e, f], [g, h]]])
```

I'm specifically interested in the latter example where the conditionals are distributed within each of the resulting array's elements.

Comment: How is an n-dimensional array expressed in the first place?

Comment: 1-dimensional: [a, b], 2-dimensional: [[a, b], [c, d]], 3-dimensional: [[[a, b], [c, d]], [[e, f], [g, h]]]

Comment: ... is your `array.fetch(x)` not equivalent to `array[x]`?

Comment: How is an n-dimensional array expressed in the first place?

Comment: Yes – `fetch(x)` is equivalent to `[x]`

Comment: Then this is purely being driven by curiosity, and not some functional real-world need? Also note that `array#fetch` already exists.

Comment: I'm aware that #fetch already exists. I'd like to understand how to write fetch using the approach of distributing the conditional through the array, rather than simply aliasing fetch.

Comment: It's mostly curiosity – yes. I don't have a concrete real-world use case for this.

Comment: I'm really not sure I follow. What do you mean "distribute the conditional through out the array"? Are you trying to generate code here? Like, you want to programatically build up an arbitrarily large if/else statement, and `eval` it? Otherwise, you "distribute" the conditional through the array with a **loop**.

Comment: @meagar yes, it's effectively a code generation problem.

Comment: Your second and third examples are not equivalent to `fetch`. `fetch` does not distinguish between array elements and non-array elements. It just returns the element at the specified index, regardless of its "type". Your method on the other hand creates a new array.

Comment: I meant logically equivalent - not necessarily having the exact same return type. This isn't really a Ruby specific question, it's a logic / algorithmic question.